# get activity().finish() not killing activity

Tags: android

I have a launcher Activity A which calls to an Activity B. B has multiple fragments. Now what I want is to be able to kill B from one of those fragments. I used `getActivity().finish()` but it would just kill the fragment.

How do I kill the activity/exit app from a fragment?

Comment: Actually it works, be sure that your fragment is not from Activity A.

Comment: It didn't in my case. The app would still be running, just the fragment would be killed but the activity would still be there.

Comment: have you tried ((ActivityB)getActivity()).finish

Comment: @ShadowDroid That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way discussed in docs: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Make `Fragment` define an interface which the `Activity` implements. Then  make call to the Activity and then let the Activity to finish(or something else).

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
    implements MyFragment.MyListener {

    public void onMyCancel() {
       finish();
    }
}


public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   private MyListener callback;

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);
     callback= (MyListener) activity;
   }

   public interface MyListener {
       public void onMyCancel();
   }

   public void btnCancel(View v) {
      callback.onMyCancel();
   }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like an elegant solution. Let me try it. Quick question: would calling an Activity back show any flickering like an activity was launched and just killed. Because the first fragment is inflated automatically upon calling Activity B.

Comment: What if I have multiple fragments trying to utilize the same functionality? Let's just say there were more than one fragments, how am I going to implement the interface when I explicitly have to declare the fragment I'm implementing the interface from?

Comment: This is just a more complicated version of `getActivity().finish()`.

Comment: Yes, in case that he can't finish activity like `getActivity().finish()`. Or what you suggest?

Comment: @AnastasiaRiss I did what you suggested. Used the Android to create an interface, implemented it, and called it from fragment but it behaved the same way as it did when I called `getActivity().finish()`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Oh, I solved it. I had implemented a broadcast listener that would clear the activity stack, and close other activities. Forgot about it as I touched the codebase after a month. I believe sending the broadcast through fragment and then calling getActivity().finish() would work fine now. But I'd keep the interface implementation. Thanks for your help, @AnastasiaRiss!

Answer (score 0):

you can only call **finish()** in your activity B , this would close your current activity.

Answer (score -3):

if you want to close your app you can simply use:

```
System.exit(0);
```

this will kill whole application process.